# The form wont open

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone help me with this? The form won't open, just flickers.

```
Private sub Button_Click (ByVal sender As system.Object,                
                                          ByVal e As system.EventArgs)  
                                          Handles Button2.Click
FrmLogin.show ()
Me.Close ()
End sub
```

Comment: that looks a lot like vb.net not mvs

Comment: Indeed, it isn't clear what MVS has to do with this question.  Did you just pick a random tag?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry2. Just help me plss @Amy.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
FrmLogin.ShowDialog ()
```

this is modal and so will pause while you fill out the form.

the form that you are closing is the main form of the app, that terminates the application. Thats how winforms works. If you want to display 2 different forms (a then b) the you need a main form plus forma and formb. Keep main form alive all the time.

Comment: thank you for the reply. The thing is my code really works earlier, what I wanted is to close form A while form B Shows and viceversa. But now it wont, it just flash the forms then the programm exits.

Comment: Tsk.! Im so dumb.! Thats it.. it works.! I forgot those things, thanks a lot pm100.

Comment: @pm100 You can close the "Main" form in vb.net by changing the Application settings  Shutdown mode from the default - When startup form closes - to - when last form closes.

Comment: @user9290081 Don't forget to click on the tick at the top left of this answer so that the op gets rep for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

change the properties of the project

the project is closed by default when the first from is closed, you can stop this by right clicking on the project and clicking properties, scroll down and you'll find a property that changes when the project will be closed/ended.

i usually change mine to "when last form closes"